# Why does Meteor develop server start up stuck, how to speed it up?

Tags: performance, debugging, meteor, startup

When starting Meteor server in developing environment with `meteor`, it always shows:

```
Downloading meteor-tool@1.3.4_4...
```

Hours past, it's still downloading this package.

Even to an example app:

```
meteor create --example todos
cd todos
meteor npm install
meteor # <-- stuck here
```

How to find out what makes it so slow?
Is there any "debug mode" to print more information about the startup process?

My environment:

- 4 CPUs, 8GB memory
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Meteor 1.4

System load < 0.2 according to `top` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7476). To resolve it, follow these steps:

1) Install a fresh version of Meteor:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

2) Within your project, make sure it's updated to use Meteor 1.4:

```
cd your_project; meteor update --release 1.4
```